# Unable to Insert into Database in ASP.NET using C# - Stack Empty

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to insert user data into a database file using Microsoft Visual Studio. I have written a form using asp.net, added database to directory, and created c# command to insert data to database, however I am getting a stack is empty error.

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the
>   current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of
>   the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [InvalidOperationException: Stack empty.]
>   System.ThrowHelper.ThrowInvalidOperationException(ExceptionResource
>   resource) +52    System.Collections.Generic.Stack`1.Pop() +6856361
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.PageInspector.Runtime.WebForms.SelectionMappingRenderTraceListener.EndRendering(TextWriter
>   writer, Object renderedObject) +85
>   System.Web.UI.RenderTraceListenerList.EndRendering(TextWriter writer,
>   Object renderedObject) +66
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +169
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer,
>   ControlAdapter adapter) +287
>   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControl(HtmlTextWriter writer) +27
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5625

Form Code:

```
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">

  <h1>An ASP.NET Form</h1>
  <br /><br />
  Please submit your information using the form below if you would like to be enrolled in our monthly newsletter.
  <br /><br />

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div class="text-right">
    Name: 
    <asp:TextBox id="pName" runat="server" Width="200px" />
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator 
        id="reqName" 
        ControlToValidate="pName"
        Style="color:Red"   
        ErrorMessage="Please enter your name!"
        runat="server"/><br>

    E-mail Address: 
    <asp:TextBox id="pEmail" runat="server" Width="200px" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator 
        id="ValidEmail" 
        ControlToValidate="pEmail" 
        Style="color:Red"
        ValidationExpression="^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$"
        ErrorMessage="Invalid Email Entry" 
        runat="server" /><br>
    <asp:Button runat="server" text="Submit" OnClick="Unnamed1_Click" ID="Button1"/><br>
        </div>

   </form>

    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" ForeColor="#FF6666"></asp:Label>

    <br />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table]"></asp:SqlDataSource>

<br />

</asp:Content>
```

C# code for database entry:

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source = (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\P\Docs\Visual Studio 2015\WebSites\WebSite2\App_Data\Database.mdf;Integrated Security = True");

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void Unnamed1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table values('" + pName.Text + "','" + pEmail.Text + "')";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        con.Close();
    }
}
```

Table created in Microsoft Visual Studio has two items pName & pEmail.

Comment: you called your table 'Table'??? Hint: Don't!

Comment: Once you've addressed your table naming issue, learn about parameterised queries and how they mitigate SQL injection.